# SQL IN equivalent with ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out how to do the equivalent of a SQL IN clause with ElasticSearch.

The query below will work but when I change it to "query": ["1589", "1590"] it does not. I believe it's doing an AND on these 2 values for the same field and I would like it to do an OR or an WHERE IN.

Works

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "userId": {
              "query": ["1589"]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Fails

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "userId": {
              "query": ["1589", "1590"]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the below should work -

```
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "userId": {
              "query": ["1589"]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "userId": {
              "query": ["1590"]
            }
          }
        }

      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Remember must is something like AND and should can be used ( alone ) to get something like OR

Comment: I guess I need to post another question specific to the C# library for ES. I would like to avoid looping through all of my users to generate an enormous query. Is there anyway to do this using an array style?

Comment: Try terms query , it works for your example but will work differently for normal strings.

Comment: Isn't this incorrect, he was asking to do `OR` not `AND`? This works if you use `should` instead of `must`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version you use, 1.7 has [terms filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) and in 2.x it is replaced by [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/query-dsl-terms-query.html). It seems that userId would be `not_analyzed` and [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-match-query.html) is "intended" for analyzed fields. They support various ways of combining the array of terms, at least the filter does.